# Can I host mcpe server on a ftp/cpanel account?

Tags: ftp, cpanel, minecraft

I have been interested in making my own MCPE server. I have found lots of online hosting websites. All of these sound great, but I want to know if there is a way to host an MCPE server on a ftp account. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: What do u mean off topic?

Comment: Did you follow the link?

Answer (score 0):

You can't host a MCPE server using a FTP account because the host will terminate the task.

You can host your own MCPE server using PocketMine-MP from your computer (See [here](https://pmmp.io/) for more info).

Otherwise you can use a VPS or Minecraft host that supports PocketMine-MP, e.g. [Aternos](https://aternos.org/en/) or [HostHorde](https://www.hosthorde.com/).

EDIT: You may need to port forward your router if you want to host a PocketMine-MP server from your computer.

Answer (score -1):

Without some form of shell access this is impossible (I'm assuming by "FTP access" you mean it's a host for only "websites" and not some sort of VPS).

Even if you managed to get the executable running I imagine your host would squash that very quickly.

Comment: Thanks. How would I go about hosting an mcpe server on a vps? Can u maybe send me to some more information.